# How to implement bootstrap (resampling) in Java efficiently

Tags: java, bigdata, resampling, statistics-bootstrap

I have a data file of 50,000,000 lines and need to bootstrap each line using Java. 
Right now I am using Math.random() to generate random number, then do the bootstrapping in a brute force way. However, it will take me forever. So i am wondering if there is any Java library help to do this efficiently or should i call other languages inside Java? Anyway my goal is to optimize the whole process. Thank you!

Comment: What is "bootstrap each lines"?

Answer (score 0):

Provided the entire dataset fits in memory (which might be feasible on a typical high-end laptop with say, 8 GB of RAM, assuming the individual lines of your file are not too long) then you might be able to use the `Resample` java class from [Weka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weka_%28machine_learning%29).  The `Resample` class comes in both a [supervised](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/filters/supervised/instance/Resample.html) as well as an [unsupervised](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/filters/unsupervised/instance/Resample.html) version.  You can download Weka [here](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/).